# How can I Count Screen Unlock Attempts on 8.0 Devices?

Tags: java, android

I want to Count Screen Unlock Attempt from devices greater than Android 8.0

I have Code which is running for devices below Android 7.0

```
layerParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                        // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        // Draws over status bar
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                , PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        playerParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        lockScreenView = new LockScreenView(this);
        callReceiver = new CallsReceiver();
        IntentFilter callFilter = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(callReceiver, callFilter);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        registerReceiver(lockScreenReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: You need to go through changes in 8.0

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer try to explain it a little bit, furthermore in your case, try to use code tag so that it can be much more readable format